# How to run Transformer and BERT models on Mali-GPU using Tensorflow Lite?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I am trying to run Transformer and BERT models on Mali-GPU using Tensorflow Lite, but as long as I know, tflite only supports some operations on GPU, not the deep learning models themself.
Do you have any ideas and tips on how I can run these Transformer and BERT models on Mali-GPU? Can I convert Tensoflow GPU model to tflite GPU model? Or is there any other library that supports transformers on embedded GPU?

Comment: I've added an answer on your new question that addresses some of these issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68442973/fully-delegate-bert-models-on-mali-gpu-using/68475828#68475828

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try running tflite version of the model on GPU delegate. TFLite Delegate will delegate as many nodes possible to the delegate (GPU in your case) and the remaining will run on CPU. You can get [Mobilebert](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/mobilebert/1/metadata/1)
2. If you have a modified version, you can try converting using the [TFLiteConverter](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert#python_api) and if you have issues file a github [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TFLiteConverter&template=60-tflite-converter-issue.md) for the TFLite team

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have tried delegate but the problem is that it doesn't support some operations. Is there a way to transfer those unsupported operations to GPU too?